# Spring JavaConfig of aop:scoped proxy

Tags: spring

What is the JavaConfig equivalent of this?

```
<!-- an HTTP Session-scoped bean exposed as a proxy
     that acts as session storage.
-->
<bean id="checkOutCounter" class="org.brightworks.genesis.client.forms.CheckOutCounter" scope="session">
    <!-- this next element effects the proxying of the surrounding bean -->
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

Tried declaring it like this but it only acts as a singleton

```
@Bean
public CheckOutCounter checkOutCounter(){
    return new CheckOutCounter();
}
```

What is the equivalent of the said xml config?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For component initialization:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
```

For @Bean:

```
@Bean
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public CheckOutCounter checkOutCounter(){
    return new CheckOutCounter();
}
```

Comment: Where's under what package is DefaultScopes in?

Comment: It's just a string constant. You can replace it with `"session"`

Comment: What about @ScopedProxy?

Comment: for some odd reason, the scope and ScopedProxy could not be imported, may I know what jar do I need for these two?

Comment: what is your spring version?

Comment: my spring version is at 4.1.6

Comment: my bad, looks that @Scope can be used again, see update